# IntelliJ IDEA not correct Run java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

After clicking Run, I see this:

[image]

How to remove it and display the result:

```
System.out.print ("ASdsddasad");
```

Or is it an IntelliJ IDEA bug?

Comment: What's error ??

Comment: Pictures of code do not count as code, they are less than useless.

Comment: Source code is text. So are error messages. Please edit your question and replace all screen shots with text.

Comment: The question itself decided.

It was necessary to press the button "Toogle Task executions" in the new version of IntelliJ IDEA. Now I see the result of my code. Thank you all. If you can then tell me how to answer your own question as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running test class, for that reason you cannot see `"ASdsddasad"`. To run the main java class, you can click on green arrow from `public static void main(String[] args)` method and choose `Run 'Main.main()'` or you can right click on any part of your class and choose the same option `Run 'Main.main()'`