# IntelliJ IDEA does not run class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Short note beforehand: saw questions( [IntelliJ IDEA running the wrong class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666760/intellij-idea-running-the-wrong-class) and [IntelliJ IDEA not correct Run java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257111/intellij-idea-not-correct-run-java-project)) answered but they didn't help.

After starting a new class(in this case CaesarCipher) and typing the code there is no option to run it.

After I press right-click on it in the source folder on the left, there is no option to run.

[image]

And in the toolbar, it is not possible to choose the class.

[image]

I'm apologizing in case I overviewed the solution.

Comment: Your class needs a `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }` method. See [Java `main` Method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-main-method)

Comment: your class is incomplete and doesn't contain an entry point, which is the very minimum in order to be able to run a class. If this puzzles you, you might want to consider stop using professional IDE's.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Understood and implemented the suggestions. Started out last week, so there is lot of place for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You should remove the enlisted errors on stacktrace from your `test.java class`.

I can see the class you created `CaesarCipher.java` doesn't have any `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

In order to run class you need to put in your main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

or you can reference your sub class in to main class like this:

public class Main{

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
         CaesarCipher caesarCipher = new CaesarCipher();
         CaesarCipher.caesarify("encrypt", shift); //put your real params values
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Don't forgot to mark solution as accepted.